# Rendering graphics: UsingFrontEnd vs using a front end

Tags: graphics, front-end, scripting, rasterize

I'm trying to understand how Graphics expressions are rendered. I create an invisible notebook, write a cell and evaluate it, then rasterize the notebook.

```
UsingFrontEnd[
nb = CreateNotebook[Visible->False];
NotebookWrite[nb,Cell["Graphics[Disk[{0,0}]]","Input"]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb,InsertResults->True];
Export["test_out.jpg",Rasterize[nb]];
]
```

If I open Mathematica and run this line, the output is as expected:

[image: Graphics renders]

But if I run this from the terminal (using `math -script myscript.m`), the Graphics object doesn't render in the output cell.

[image: Graphics doesn't render]

Is there any way to change this behavior, so that I get the same result running from within Mathematica or from the terminal? I'm running 12.1, if that's important. I'm going to try to work around this using `Export`, but for some parts of my application I really do need `Rasterize`, so it would be convenient if I could use it in all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Where's the difference?

In a command line mode, evaluators default to use `InputForm`(raw wolfram language expressions), rather than `StandardForm` (which `MakeBoxes`).

### Effective (but not canonical) solution

I can't find any way to specify the default form for evalaution yet. But we can make the boxes on our own.

Replace the `Cell` expression in your code to:

```
Cell["Graphics[Disk[{0,0}]]","Input",CellEvaluationFunction->(MakeBoxes@@MakeExpression[#,StandardForm]&)]
```

Then the code will work for the **command line environment**.

### Understand it better

To reproduce the problem in the **notebook environment**, use such a `CellEvaluationFunction`: `(#1&)`.

### Additional advice

The kernel can do `MakeBoxes` and `Export` of `Graphics`, so `UsingFrontEnd` is not essential for most rendering requirements. `$DisplayFunction` may help.