# Is there any way to change the box-formatting behavior thoroughly?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, cells, implementation-details, boxes

### Background

The box-formmating behavior is affected by the downvalues of the symbol `MakeBoxes`. But the formatting behavior is not exactly `MakeBoxes`, but seems to be the same to menu command "ConvertTo/StandardForm". There's an example for the difference: [159959](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159959/tagbox-interpretationbox-vs-convertto-standardform).

Another key process of evaluations in Mathematica is sending the content of evaluating input cell to evaluators. This can be strongly changed by setting the option `CellEvaluationFunction` (however, for example, this way can't handle multi-line cell, see: [29264](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29264/what-is-the-real-default-cellevaluationfunction)).

### Question

Similarly, is there any way to change the **box-formatting behavior** *more than* changing the definition of `MakeBoxes`?

### Related Question

(Not essential for understanding this question. You can skip them if you are not interested.)

1. Is any way to change the **cell-creation behavior** which is similar to `If[# =!= Null, CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes@#, "Output"(* , ... *)]] &`?
2. Difference between "ConvertTo/InputForm" and `MakeExpression`([76056](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76056/function-equal-to-ctrlshifti)), "ConvertTo/StandardForm" and `MakeBoxes`. (As [Itai Seggev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4848/itai-seggev) mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175482/schr%c3%b6dingers-matrixform-feature-or-bug), they uses `` BoxForm`ConvertForm ``)
3. Why the default form used for output-formatting differs in different environments of the kernel(approximately `ToString[#, InputForm]&` for command-line, `BoxData@ToBoxes[#, StandardForm]&` for notebook)? Can we choose a form for it programmatically? See: [226209](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226209/rendering-graphics-usingfrontend-vs-using-a-front-end)

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want to change or what should be the effect and in what circumstances. Currently my interpretation is that `Format` is a potential answer but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Kuba Nice. Definitions to `Format[_, InputForm]` affects "Related Question 3"(MSE 226209) successfully. But this question seeks for a function or method for interference which has a similar position to `CellEvaluationFunction` in the box-explaination process. Perhaps such a method does not exist.

Comment: CellEvaluationFunction is more about parsing or on the route from boxes to expressions rather than formatting which is about expressions to boxes. I am still confused :) sorry.

Comment: @Kuba I know that. What I meant is, we can set `CellEvaluationFunction` to interfere "parsing or on the route from boxes to expressions" when I cannot find a similar way to interfere "formatting which is about expressions to boxes".

Comment: Now, I'm able to get an better way to discribe my question. I will post my edit later.

Comment: I do have a better understand to this now. But I am a bit lazy to update it here...